# Format output from CMD into one line

Tags: command-line, cmd, wmic

I want to get information about the RAM and output it into a text file. I have this command:

```
wmic memorychip get Serialnumber, Capacity > memory.txt
```

The output has this format:

```
SerialNumber Capacity
B1246960     1073741824   
643A1552     2147483648
```

But I want the output to be a one-liner. Something like this:

```
643A1552,643A1552   1073741824,2147483648
```

How to obtain a one line output?

Comment: You want to try that output-requirement again?

Comment: What output-requirement? @Magoo

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: The "one line output" that you have specified. It reads "**643A1552**,643A1552   1073741824,2147483648"

Comment: Why do you need output on one line? What if there are multiple outputs?

Comment: Because we have started a system and it parses data from the text file. The memorychip info is an additional so we need to keep the output as simplified/short as possible so that we won't have much adjustments in our code @Bill_Stewart

Comment: Actually it lists the columns in alphabetical order, regardless of the order you specify them, so Capacity is listed before SerialNumber.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
wmic memorychip get Serialnumber, Capacity, Speed > memory.txt

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3" %%i in ('type memory.txt') do (
  set cp=!cp!,%%i
  set sn=!sn!,%%j
  set sp=!sp!,%%k
)
REM remove first comma:
echo RAM %sn:~1%    %cp:~1%   %sp:~1% >x.txt
```

Note dbenhams comment: `Actually it lists the columns in alphabetical order, regardless of the order you specify them, so Capacity is listed before SerialNumber. –  dbenham`

**EDIT** to comments "three columns": "caption" is a bad choice here, because it's value contains a space ("Physical Memory"), so tokenization is wrong. I used "speed" instead in my example (which is a much more valuable info).

Comment: Still the same output. It's not a one-liner

Comment: for me, it is. What does your output look like?

Comment: ah wait. You mean, `memory.txt` is still the same? I didn't alter it. You may add `>memory.txt` to the last `echo`line to orverwite it with the one-liner.

Comment: Still with 3 columns and 2 rows

Comment: how about with 3 columns. wmic memorychip get Serialnumber, Capacity, Caption > memory.txt @stephan

Comment: Just add another token (`tokens=1,2,3`or `tokens=1-3`). As the output is in alphabetical order, token 1 would be capacity (`%%i`), token 2=caption (`%%j`) and token 3=serial (`%%k`).  And add another `set ct=` inside the loop and adapt the `echo`line.

Comment: for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3" %%i in ('type memory.txt') //

Comment: set cp=!cp!,%%i  set sn=!sn!,%%j set sz=!sz!,%%k
echo RAM %cp:~1%    %sn:~1% %sz:~1% > D:\memory.txt I did this but not a one liner

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do a "one-line" output like that in PowerShell:

```
$sn = $capacity = ""
get-wmiobject Win32_PhysicalMemory | foreach-object {
  $sn += ",{0}" -f $_.SerialNumber
  $capacity += ",{0}" -f $_.Capacity
}
"{0}   {1}" -f $sn.Substring(1),$capacity.SubString(1)
```